# How to make it a descending order using List?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a code that list all records. But i want it to be descending order. heres my code:

```
<%
ChangeRequestDetails changeRequestDetails = new ChangeRequestDetails();
List<ChangeRequestBean> changerequestlistchangeRequestDetails.getAllChangeRequests();
%>
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>Requestor</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Category</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Priority</th>                        
       <th>Approval</th>
    </tr>
    <%
for (ChangeRequestBean changerequest: changerequestlist) {
%>
    <tr class="gradeB">
    <td><%=changerequest.getChangerequestid()%></td>
    <td><%=changerequest.getUserdivisionid()%></td>
    <td><%=changerequest.getDefchangerequest()%></td>
    <td><%=changerequest.getCategory()%></td>
    <td><%=changerequest.getChangerequesttype()%></td>
    <td><%=changerequest.getChangerequestpriority()%></td>
    <!--<td><%=changerequest.getDatestamp()%></td>-->
    <td><%=changerequest.getApproval()%></td>
            </tr>
    <%}%>
</table>
```

Please help, the reason that i want it in descending order because i want to see the recently added records. thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Is the list already sorted in ascending order?  If so, just use `Collections.reverse(changerequestlist);` to reverse the sort order

Comment: @Ireeder +1 yes it is in ascending order. Thank you sir it greatly help! :) i can now view the records in descending sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the  Comparable inerface in your ChangeRequestBean  if not already done.

Change the  public int compareTo(ChangeRequestBean  bean) according to your need below code will sort based on the changerequestid.

```
    class ChangeRequestBean implements Comparable<ChangeRequestBean> {

        public int compareTo(ChangeRequestBean  bean) {
             return this.changerequestid   - bean.changerequestid ;
        }       
    }
```

Use the below code to reverse sort your list.

```
  Collections.reverse(changerequestlist);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list is already sorded in ascending order, you can use ListIterator to iterate in reverse order

```
<%
ListIterator<ChangeRequestBean> iterator = changerequestlistchangeRequestDetails.listIterator(changerequestlistchangeRequestDetails.size());
while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
    ChangeRequestBean changerequest = iterator.previous();
%>
...
<%
}
%>
```

In this case you needn't reverse your list every time when you need to change order.

If you need to sort list before, you can use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort your beans with specified Comparator. In this case you can use different comparators to sort your list using different ordering rules.

Comment: Yes sir the sequence is in descending order.